Getting text on imap_tools with python only able for fowarded e-mail
I’ve developed a Python script using imap_tools to retrieve billing information sent to my email.
However, some companies include the necessary information only in the body of the email. In some cases, I can extract this information using the imap_tools.text attribute, but other times it doesn’t work. Interestingly, if I manually forward the email to myself, the information becomes readable using imap_tools.text.

Is there a way to automatically retrieve this information?

Alternatively, does anyone know how to set up an automatic email forwarding (not resending) in Gmail?


Here's my code:
def get_mailbox(folder: str = None) -> mailbox:
    mails = mailbox.MailBox('imap.gmail.com')
    return mails.login(username='username@gmail.com',
                       password='password,
                       initial_folder=folder)

def get_emails_from_folder(folder: str):
    caixa_emails = get_mailbox(folder=folder)
    return list(caixa_emails.fetch(AND(seen=False)))

emails = get_emails_from_folder('Billings')
    if not emails:
        return {}
    for email in emails:
        text = email.text

Thanks in advance!

At lib docs:

Email has 2 basic body variants: text and html. Sender can choose to
include: one, other, both or neither(rare).

lib athor.
